# Spring Redis Hash operations SCAN

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis

I'm doing `Spring Redis`, I put the key as

```
redistemplate.opsForHash().put("Customer", Customer.class, List<Customers>)
```

I want to search from the `List<>`,

```
ScanOptions options = ScanOptions.scanOptions().match(pattern).count(1).build();

Cursor<Entry<Object, Object>> keys = redistemplate.opsForHash().scan("Customer", options);
```

Also not working. Please help!!

Comment: can you get data by using ScanOptions.NONE

Comment: ScanOptions.NONE works but fetching everything not matching the pattern.

Comment: what is your pattern

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the scan operation matches keye not match the values.
When using a Hash to store values it should be as below:
`redisTemplate.opsForHash().put("key", keyInsideHash, value);`
So the actual key of a Redis record is `key` (You use it to fetch the Hash). `keyInsideHash` is the key of actual value you need to store. So first to get the hash then get the value from it. 
For example: `redisTemplate.opsForHash().put("customerKey1", "FirstName", "MyFirstName");` and `redisTemplate.opsForHash().put("customerKey1", "LastName", "MyLastName");`. in this example we store in the same hash with key `"customerKey1"` two entries `["FirstName","MyFirstName"]` and `["LastName", "MyLastName"]` .
In your case you have a List instead of `"MyFirstName"`.
If you need to scan a Hash, you do as below (scanning the keys inside the hash not values):

```
saveToDbCacheRedisTemplate.execute(new RedisCallback<List<String>>() {

            @Override
            public List<String> doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {
                ScanOptions options = ScanOptions.scanOptions().match("pattern").count(1).build();;
                Cursor<Entry<byte[], byte[]>> entries = connection.hScan("customerKey1".getBytes(), options);
                List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
                if(entries!=null)
                    while(entries.hasNext()){
                        Entry<byte[], byte[]> entry = entries.next();
                        byte[] actualValue = entry.getValue();
                        result.add(new String(actualValue));
                    }

                return result;
            }

        });
```

Comment: So Nebras, there is no way that I can scan values?

I have stored the keys like this,
redistemplate.opsForHash().put("Customer", Customer.class, List<Customer>);

When I try,
hscan Customer 0 match *Custom* 

I see values are being fetched.

Comment: My requirement is to store billions of record in Redis and fetch it as per the user wish, the user can do a search, sort each column etc., Is it possible in Redis? I'm using java to load into Redis, so I can't load a million record at once, I'll have to split the million records into 100000 keys with 100 records each and store. If I store like that, is possible to search/sort?

Comment: I changed the hash to,

keyHash = getString(data from DB);

redistemplate.opsForHash().put("Customer", keyHash, getString(data from DB));

I did try Cursor<Entry<byte[], byte[]>> keys =redistemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().hScan("Customer".getBytes(), options); 

Its still not fetching the pattern.

Comment: I think you can do so.. however, find below link that helps you to best store your values using redis hashs http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value.

Comment: Nebras, search only happens with keys, not values at all, so if i have to implement search, i'll have to store values as keys. I dont think this is a correct way of doing it. Even in the HMSET or something, I should still use the value as key to fetch.

Comment: yes that it is. Try to depend on redis structure to have the best performance. Redis is a key-value cache concept. If you find this helpful please mark as answer or vote up ;)

Comment: Okay, at high level, it is ok to store key as value to do search. But when you have billion of records and to search according to the records (value), it is still too much. I'll agree that as an answer, but not be very happy.

Comment: Can you please tell me how the SORT works? I dont get answers for some important questions.

Comment: please find this link: http://redis.io/commands/sort (Sort operation documentation of Redis).

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue today, and I find my *redis* server version is
`redis_version:2.6.16`, and the *redis.io* says that this command is available since **2.8.0**. See: https://redis.io/commands/scan.

Hope that can help you!

Answer (score 1):

When use spring redistemplate, try below to iterate fields and values in a redis hash

```java
  /**
   * hScan provided by redis template is for iterating fields and values within a redis HashMap, not among keys
   * @param key
   * @return
   */
  public Map<String, String> hscanAll(final String key) {
    return hscanPattern(key, "*");
  }

  /**
   * Returns the map with fields that match the given {@Code fieldPattern} and values from the HashMap of the given redis {@Code key}
   * @param key
   * @param fieldPattern
   * @return
   */
  public Map<String, String> hscanPattern(final String key, final String fieldPattern) {
    return (Map<String, String>)
        redisTemplate.execute(
            (RedisCallback<Map<String, String>>)
                connection -> {
                  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                  try (Cursor<Map.Entry<byte[], byte[]>> cursor =
                      connection.hScan(
                          key.getBytes(),
                          new ScanOptions.ScanOptionsBuilder().match(fieldPattern).count(200).build())) {

                    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                      Map.Entry<byte[], byte[]> entry = cursor.next();
                      map.put(
                          new String(entry.getKey(), "Utf-8"),
                          new String(entry.getValue(), "Utf-8"));
                    }
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                  }
                  return map;
                });
  }
```